# Как поменять миниатюру категории WooCommerce через PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

У некоторых категорий нет изображений, я пытаюсь добавить им изображение первого товара. Каким способом можно добавить миниатюру категории?

У меня есть term_id категории, thumbnail_id товара тоже удалось получить
Пробовал эти функции:

```
set_post_thumbnail( '1456', '22762' );
update_post_meta( '1456', '_thumbnail_id', '22762');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы добавляете миниатюру для категории то и таблица должна быть соответствующей

```
update_term_meta( 1456, 'thumbnail_id', 22762);
```